# Latex with free draw support for note taking

Tags: code, notes

I'm self studying math and computer science and am wondering how people like to organize their notes.

This is because sometimes math is very symbol heavy and hard to write out, but sometimes it's helpful to have code too that you can copy/paste/run/modify/test later when you re reference your notes. Doing everything on paper makes it harder to organize and test.

So the ideal setup would have:

1. Ability to write/paste code.
2. Ability to write LateX.
3. Ability to draw freehand pictures whenever necessary.

What would allow this?

Comment: Welcome, i am not sure this is a LaTeX question. Seems you are looking out for special software that can also lead you to the candy mountain. Or maybe just handwriting recognition software?

Comment: It would also need to support source code text and LateX.

Comment: LaTeX is text, source code is text.

Comment: What is CS? I know it as  either 2-chlorobenzalmalononitrile  or Counter-Strike.

Comment: Yes, but not everything renders both, plus handwriting / drawing

Comment: @KolaB. Computer Science

Comment: @Nakano Oh, indeed! My fault.

Answer (score 2):

Since two months I use [LaTeX4technics](https://www.latex4technics.com) almost every day. I think this site covers some of your aspects. 
You're able to write LaTeX-code on this site (supported by a lot of useful tools).

I use this service mostly because of the note system. 
You can create equations or LaTeX-projects and they get stored as note if you want. If you're a user (for free) you can label your equation with a title and protect it with a password. With your user account you can access all your notes you have ever taken. 
[image: equation list]
That's great because you can reuse a lot of equations with a minimum of effort and organize yourself. 
This saves time when you e.g. write papers and you need recurring equations in your main LaTeX projects.

Some weeks ago they announced to build up a equation database. I think they want to build up something like a search engine for high quality LaTeX equations which gets filled by the community. The goal is to save your time by using LaTeX code snippets which other users have already written.

At the moment they don't offer hand writing recognition.

EDIT:

You also could use [sharelatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/) if you want to organize bigger LaTeX-projects. But you can save only a certain number of projects for free. Furthermore for me it's not always necessary to set up a complete LaTeX-project, a thing that is a must on sharelatex.

At the moment they also don't offer hand writing recognition.

Answer (score 1):

I know and app to do this, but working only in windows... Inlage...

http://www.inlage.com/home

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is not really an answer. Please elaborate on what this app does. As it is now written, it's rather commentary.

Comment: This seems to be supported, as suggested by the [Inlage features](http://www.inlage.com/features).